# How to send a file from Adobe Draw to Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-draw

I've the updated version of Adobe Draw on my iPad Pro and Illustrator on my MacBook Pro. If I tap the drop-down-menu in Draw to send my file over, there is a loading icon until a small window pops up: 'sent!' But nothing happens on my MacBook in Illustrator. Also there is no way that I have two different accounts connected. What else could it be?

Comment: Items show up in the CC "Libraries" panel.

Comment: No.. there are no new items in my Libraries. The option should open a new document in Illustrator CC instantly. It's called "open with" > "Illustrator" or "Photoshop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The Creativ Cloud App on my Macbook seem to failed. A restart helped, after that all documents opened automatically in Illustrator CC.

Comment: Yup, the CC app often fails to connect with the CC Libraries, even on PC's. Hopefully they'll fix that soon. It's damned annoying.